# How to Re-train custom yolo weights?

Tags: object-detection, yolo, darknet

I have done a custom detection in YOLOv3 over 3 classes, but the detections were not accurate so I want to retrain my custom YOLO weights with more images, but
when I run it with new images it immediately finished, what is it that I have done wrong?

Here how I train it

```
 !./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/yolov3_custom.cfg yolov3_custom_last.weights
```

The content of obj.data:

```
classes = 3
train = data/train.txt
valid = data/test.txt
names = data/obj.names
backup = /mydrive/yolov3/backup/
```

The content of yolov3_custom.cfg:

```
# Training
batch=64
subdivisions=16
width=416
height=416
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1
learning_rate=0.001
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 6000
policy=steps
steps=4800,5400
scales=.1,.1
```

Comment: More information is required. What are the contents of **obj.data** and **yolov3_custom.cfg**files?

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef hi , check the edit. thanks.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: 1. I think, there should be some kind of error log if it is getting stopped by some issue. Can you confirm if the training getting finished with error log or not?
2. what is the value of "max_batches" you have set for your 1st training and 2nd training?
3. Are you using the last iteration weight from 1st training for your 2nd training?

Comment: @HamidShatu 1.there is no error, 2. max_batches = 6000 for the 1st and the 2nd, 3.yes I'm using the last weights that reaches the max batches, is that why it is stopped? should I change the max_batches to be double the first training? thanks for the respond

Comment: @s683 I'm assuming as you guessed that, since the max_batches for both of the training is same and you're using the last weight from 1st training, that's why training is getting finished once you start it. Yes, please double the max_batches value and trigger the train again and observe what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change the path to the weights file in the command for training the model and run it again. There is no need to update the `max_batches` parameter or change the configuration file in any way. The framework is aware of how many iterations that a given set of weights has been trained for when retraining a model. For instance, if you are to stop after 2000 iterations in the initial training process, when retraining using the set of weights that was created as a result, it will begin at the 2001th iteration.

Answer (score 1):

@Hamid Shatu. You are correct. You Need to update your max_batches= and also check your Weight file Name.

Comment: post this as a comment instead of answer!